# How to adjust the frame for iCarouselTypeLinear view to move to top

Tags: ios, objective-c, icarousel

How to adjust the frame of the containerView in linearType ICarousel View to required height from origin, But it is fixed to the middle of the view as shown in the Image, as I tried to set the frame as shown in below code.

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(__unused iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view  {    
UILabel *label = nil;  
//create new view if no view is available for recycling  
//    if (view == nil)  
//    {  
    view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIObjects widthOfTheElement:267], [UIObjects heightOfTheElement:172])];  
    ((UIImageView *)view).image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.imagesArray objectAtIndex:index]];  
//        view.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;  
//        view.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];  
    label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:view.bounds];  
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];  
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;   
    label.font = [label.font fontWithSize:50];  
    label.tag = 1;  
    [view addSubview:label];  
if (index==0)   
{  
    label.text = @"ramki";    
}  
else  
{  
}  
return view;  
}
```

[image: Pleae click here to view image].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iCarousels have various settings that let you adjust the placement, 3D angle, and other parameters of the carousel. There is a setting that lets you move the carousel up or down in its view. Check the docs.

Comment: Can u please name it (setting name ), I tried but I did not found anything.

Comment: I haven't used iCarousel in over a year, and would have to go hunt down the docs just like you. There is a demo app that ships with iCarousel that has sliders that let you move the carousel around on it's enclosing view. Take a look at that app.

Comment: Looks like the property is `contentOffset`

Comment: Thank you @Duncan, I set Height of the Content offset to my required height, It worked.